# IF ELSE condition is always going to the ELSE

Tags: javascript, node.js, postman

Here is my POST request:

```
router.post('/', (req, res) => {
    let body = { ...req.body };
    let odd = new Array();
    let even = new Array();
    let is_success = true;

    body.array.forEach((element) => {
        if (Number.isInteger(element)) {
            if (element % 2 == 0) {
                even.push(element);
            } else {
                odd.push(element);
            }
        } else {
            is_success = false;
            return;
        }
    });
    if (is_success) {
        res.status(200).json({
            is_success: `${is_success}`,
            user_id: 'john_doe_17091999',
            odd: `${odd}`,
            even: `${even}`,
        });
    } else
        res.status(200).json({
            is_success: `${is_success}`,
            user_id: 'john_doe_17091999',
        });
});
```

The condition is_success is not becoming true and that takes it to the else condition always. What I am trying to do is take the array and return odd and even arrays if all input elements are Integers:

```
{
"array": ["1", "2", "3"] 
}
```

Response:

```
{
"successful": true,
"odd": [1, 3],
"even": [2],
}
```

What it is always responding with:

```
{
    "is_success": "false",
    "user_id": "john_doe_17091999"
}
```

Comment: Well, those aren't numbers, they're strings...

Comment: Why do you call `if/else` a loop? A loop is something that repeats. `forEach()` is a loop.

Comment: If you want to know if a string contains a valid integer, call `parseInt()` to convert it to a number, then use `Number.isNaN()`.

Comment: I was frustrated lol, but thanks I edited and removed the word LOOP. I did apply parseInt but it did not work for some reason.

Comment: @Barmar Given that OP is checking whether the number is an integer or not, using parseInt is not the way to go, as it will convert any number (be it an integer or a float) to an integer. In this case, Number.isInteger() will always return true. Putting a '+' before the element will convert it to a number if it is, in fact, a number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your array contains strings. You need to convert them to numbers before you can run Number.isInteger() on them, otherwise it will always return 'false'. You can do that by putting a '+' before the element. See below.

`Number.isInteger(+element)`

Comment: Can you link to docs for this + method? I did not know this, thanks a lot!

Comment: @Amay https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Unary_plus

Comment: Glad! I will accept this as answer.

Comment: @Amay Please bear in mind that the unary plus will convert false to 0 and true to 1, and also convert an empty string to 0

Comment: Oh, I see, good to know.

Answer (score 0):

You must cast every **element** to **Number** before using the **Number.isInteger** otherwise you'll get false.

Example: Number.isInteger("2") will return false
Number.isInteger(Number("2")) will return true